# Fubini-Study metric as the natural metric in CP^n

Tags: riemannian-geometry, projective-space, quantum-information

I am currently trying to understand how to show that the Fubini-Study metric is the natural metric in the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$ in the context of Hilbert space corresponding to some quantum system. I've been trying to follow the explanation on a paper called "Connecting geometry and performance of two-qubit parameterized quantum circuits" but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

In short, the paper argues that the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ can be constructed by considering the tangent space $T_{[|\psi\rangle]}\mathbb{C}P^n$ on a point $[|\psi\rangle ]$, where $[|\psi\rangle ]$ denotes the equivalency class given by $[|\psi\rangle ]=\{a|\psi\rangle: a\in \mathbb{C}\}$. Given that tangent space, the Fubini-Study metric can then be defined in terms of the hermitian inner product $h$ of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ by taking the orthogonal complement using the operator $P_{\psi}^{\perp}=I-|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ to evaluate the inner product on  $T_{|\psi\rangle}\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, relying on the natural isomorphism $T_{|\psi\rangle}\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \cong \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, resulting in
$$
h(\phi_1, \phi_2)=\langle\phi_1|P^{\perp}_\psi|\phi_2\rangle = \langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle-\langle\phi_1|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\phi_2\rangle
$$

This expression is also known as the quantum geometric tensor in the literature. The Fubini-Study metric is supposed to be the real part of this expression. The paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02593) (pages 4 and 5) if anyone wishes to take a closer look.

In hopes to better understand this, I've been trying to come up with a more detailed derivation but I haven't had much success, so, starting from scratch:

Consider a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with inner product $h:\mathcal{H} \times\mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ defied by
$$
h(\phi, \psi)= \langle\phi|\psi\rangle= G(\phi, \psi) + iF(\phi, \psi)
$$
where $G(\phi, \psi)$ and $F(\phi, \psi)$ are the real and imaginary parts of $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, respectively.
The projective state space $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{H})=\mathbb{C}P^n$ can be constructed by taking th quotient $\mathcal{H}/\sim$ where the equivalency is given by
$$
\psi \sim \phi \iff \psi=a\phi; \ \ \ a\in\mathbb{C}.
$$

I've been advised to consider the canonical projection
$$
\pi:\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{C}P^{n}\\
z\mapsto[z]
$$
and take its pushforward map
$$
\pi_*:T_z\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^{n}
$$
to show that, when restricted to $z^{\perp}$, $\pi_*$ defines an isomorphism, but I've been unable to do so. I belive it has to do with the fact that $T_z\mathbb{C}^{n+1}=[z] \oplus z^{\perp}$, as pointed out in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366739/fubini-study-metric-induced-by-submersion) related question.

So I would like to know how can i prove this and, from there, how can I use this to arrive at the expression for the so called quantum geometric tensor and, thus, the Fubini-Study metric, showing that it is the natural metric in $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

I'm sorry if my reasoning is sloppy, I have a background in physics and only recently started taking an interest in learning math more seriously, specially geometry, so any help is much appreciated.